# reload on Deferred resolution

Tags: jquery

I am trying to trigger a page reload after bunch of ajax calls have been completed. Following is the code:

```
var calls = jQuery.map(urls, function(url) {
  return $.post(url);
});
$.when(calls)
  .done(function() {
    window.location.reload();
  });
```

This code is almost always seem to trigger reload before all ajax requests complete and I see in Firebug that some ajax requests are getting cancelled. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks James and sorry for not doing a thorough search.

Comment: Not a problem.  I only found it easily because I was first able to determine the cause.

Answer (score -1):

Use $.then such as;

```
$.when(eventHandler1).then(eventHandler2).done(function(){
 window.location.reload();
});
```